# Invoking a class method when the object has two classes in R

Tags: r, class, methods

I have an object with two classes: "data.frame" and "subject".  I want to print this object in a manner specific to the class "subject".  I can define such a method for print for the class "subject" but I can not invoke it on my object.  How can I do this?

```
       a <- data.frame(id = c(1,1))
       class(a) <- c("data.frame", "subject")
       setGeneric("print")
       setMethod("print",
                  c(x = "subject"),
                  "Printout for class 'subject'")
```

Comment: Typically you would use `class(a) <- c("subject", "data.frame")` instead of `class(a) <- c("data.frame", "subject")`.

Comment: R generally reads values left to right. The dispatch engine uses the first class that has the desired method.